# Filtering specific sql resultset and stacking two tables vertically

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SQL statement

```
SELECT parent.wonum, parent.parent, parent.status, parent.description, child.wonum as Child_Wonum, child.parent as Child_parent, child.status as Child_status FROM (select * from max7503.dbo.workorder as w where w.parent is null and w.worktype = 'INSP' AND w.changeby = 'XLI') as parent
left JOIN
(select * from max7503.dbo.workorder as child where child.parent is not null and child.worktype = 'INSP' AND changeby = 'XLI') AS child
ON parent.wonum = child.parent 
WHERE parent.status = 'COMP'
```

my result set :

[image: IMG]

A parent can have multiple children.  How these two are linked is the parents wonum is equal to the child's parent.
What I am looking to do is not not join the table side by side. But to stack them vertically.  I have tried using a union but I must follow the logic I have here. The flow must be is if a parent's status is equal to comp then query the children associated with that parent.  But if the parent status is not comp. Do not query the children associated with it.  I am new to sql so any insight would be helpful thank you.

EDIT:
 What I am looking to achieve is I have one table I pull from.

**Workorder Table**

```
wonum     parent     status     worktype  
=====     ======     ======     ========
1000      NULL       COMP       INSP
1002      1000       COMP       INSP
1005      1000       COMP       INSP
1006      NULL       APPR       INSP
1008      1006       COMP       INSP
1009      1006       COMP       INSP
1010      1006       APPR       INSP
1011      1006       COMP       INSP
```

**Desired Output**

```
wonum     parent     status     worktype
=====     ======     ======     ========
1000      NULL       COMP       INSP
1002      1000       COMP       INSP
1005      1000      COMP       INSP
```

By this small sample data.  I have two parents ( 1000 and 1006).  1006  still has children elements with the status of APPR.  I would like to query the parent and the children associated to that parent. All with the status COMP.

Comment: If I could have my logic changed around to do a union instead of a join that would work as well.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server? What version are you using?

Comment: I am looking for the result set to be stacked vertically. So I want to add new rows. Not add Columns.

Comment: Any chance you could paste some sample data into your question? screenshots are hard to see and hard to copy data from.  A sample of the data and the desired output would be tops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow what you're after here, but if you want to 'stack' the records and they're all coming from the same table, why not use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM    max7503.dbo.workorder
WHERE   worktype = 'INSP'
    AND changeby = 'XLI'
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent,wonum)
        ,parent
        ,wonum
```

If that's not what you're after, showing desired output with some sample data would be helpful.

Update:  Based on updated question it's apparent you do need the `JOIN` to filter records, best done in a recursive cte, and after filtering you can then use `ORDER BY` to format output:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT wonum, parent
              FROM Table1
              WHERE Status = 'COMP'
                AND Parent IS NULL
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT a.wonum, a.parent
              FROM Table1 a
              JOIN cte b
               ON a.parent = b.wonum
              WHERE Status = 'COMP')
SELECT *
FROM    Table1 a
WHERE   worktype = 'INSP'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM cte b
               WHERE a.wonum = b.wonum)
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent,wonum)
        ,parent
        ,wonum
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ef44/5/0)

Comment: Since I preform a join on the parent. I will receive multiple parents . I am looking to get distinct parent and children.

Comment: @DerekParker There is no `JOIN` in my answer, because all data is coming from the same table and you're talking about displaying results vertically. This would list a parent record, then all the children associated.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I am looking for an output.  Your way works very similar to the way I used union. The query you had provided is very similar to my results I had with union.  I think my edit gives a better idea on what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: Any useful crash tutorial on utilizing CTE's and nested queries such as that?

Comment: Can't think of any good sources, but searching for `recursive cte example` and `correlated subquery example` might yield some helpful things.